# I need to change the python consule in gedit to Python 2

Tags: python, gedit

Can I change the python consule in gedit to use python 2 instead of 3? I have gedit 3.16.2 , and Python 2 is my default in everything else.

Comment: What system are you using (windows/mac/unix)? Are you aware that gedit has nothing to do with your python version? Gedit is just a text editor tool. The python console thing I believe is just a plugin for it?

Comment: gedit likely uses Python 3 internally and opens up access to an interactive shell in the same process. To be honest, you should be switching to Python 3 as soon as possible anyways.

Comment: I'm on fedora22... Yes, I was afraid it was specific to the plug in. Oh well. I didn't really need it anyways. I was just hoping there was a way. I like IDLE , and I play around with Pycharm, but just using the plain old text editor is growing on me. Thanks anyhow.